# How can I prevent SASS from moving import directives to the top of the rendered file?

Tags: sass

I've recently used SASS to create a WordPress theme. I used a technique like this (http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/) to get SASS to compile the required CSS doc block with no issue.

Now I'm trying to use SASS to make the stylesheet for a child theme - this requires a CSS @import of the parent theme's style.css. This works fine, but it's compiling the @import before the CSS doc block! Any ideas how to render them in the intended order? I tried to put the CSS @import inside the SASS @import of a partial, but it still happens!

For example if this is my SASS:

```
/*!
Theme Name: Themey Name
Description: Theme Description
Version: 1.0
Template: parent-theme
*/

@import url(../parent-theme/style.css);
```

It is rendering out like:

```
@import url(../parent-theme/style.css);

/*
Theme Name: Themey Name
Description: Theme Description.
Version: 1.0
Template: parent-theme
*/
```

I really want that doc block first!

Comment: huh? whats the problem please post some code...

Comment: Now your question makes sense. SASS seems to move import statements seems to the very top.

Comment: Is there a way to override the order? Will all preprocessors do this (I'm using Fire App)

Comment: It also happens in Codekit. I guess CSS 1 required `@import` at the top of files. My solution is going to be not to import the parent theme at all, but compile the parent theme SASS into the child theme style.css.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this? I started to work on a child theme as well and am having the exact problem. Seems I'm going to have to work the "old way" with this CSS. What an irony: We want to work with Sass but Sass is not letting us do it, so we have to go back to the old ways of writing CSS :p

Comment: Is the parent theme also SASS? You could just recompile into the child theme instead of doing the @import. Less http requests!

Comment: Yes, copy the parent's `style.css` and import it as a SASS partial!

Comment: For WordPress: recently I read somewhere that the comment template thing does not need to be on top of `style.css` anymore, just has to be in the first 2000 or something lines. Can't find the link now for the life of me... Just saying, I would still very much like `@import` to not mess up with order of directives.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the @-import at the top of the file shoudl be solved according to the following comment:

Jonathan Warren
Permalink to comment# OCTOBER 10, 2012
In the latest WordPress (3.4.2) you don’t need the comment block at the start of your style.css for it to be recognised, just a folder in your themes directory with an empty index.php and style.css will do.

Found in the post on:
http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/

Tested this on wp 3.5.x - works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my "workaround":

```
/*!
Theme Name: Themey Name
Description: Theme Description
Version: 1.0
Template: parent-theme
*/

@media any {
    @import url(../parent-theme/style.css);
}
```

Comment: @sam Um... yes, it does compile??

Comment: `@media any` isn't a supported media type.